# ASP.Net MVC Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, membership

I'm aware this has been asked a million times, but all I could find is either very simple scenarios or over-complicated ones that aren't of much use to me (like the huge MembershipProvider sample implementation at MSDN).

Here's my problem : I have a database with a Users table. A User has a username, password and some other important information. What I want is being able to have a page require authentication so if the user has already subscribed to the application he can authenticate using his uname/pwd, otherwise he can sign up by filling in all the required information. No roles, no special privileges, nothing, just plain simple authentication.

I guess it should be something straightforward, I just wanna make sure that it's decoupled enough and don't wanna go writing my custom authentication system if there is a built-in one already available and tested.

Thanks.

**EDIT :**
Just for clarification, I don't need a custom MembershipProvider,  I'm using a SQL Server database so the default provider should work just fine. The problem really is how I can simply define my own set of required information for the user.

**ANSWER :**
I ultimately had to derive my own MembershipProvider class and override the methods I was interested in. It was much simpler than I thought ans worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Using Visual Studio (2008, 2010), create an ASP.NET MVC2 application (no worries, I'm not suggesting to keep it, just use it for studying). In the created code have a look at the interface IMembershipService:

```
public interface IMembershipService {
   int MinPasswordLength { get; }
   bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password);
   MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email);
   bool ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
}
```

In your application you can implement this interface any way you like, e.g. with a class that uses the information you have stored in the Users table.

Another example would be a class that uses a WCF-based web service. This is an approach I used in one of my recent projects.

All the rest is already wired up and ready to go.

Comment: Implementing IMembershipService in my own Membership class isn't much different from creating my own authentication system, it's just an interface. I'd like to take advantage of something of a higher level, that is if it's possible at all. Anyway, if it turns out it's the only way to do it then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

That's really simple,
just call

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
```

and put an `[Authorize]` attribute on the controllers or actions that you want to restrict access

---

also, in case you're gonna need roles in future you can look here

http://code.google.com/p/asms-md/source/browse/trunk/WebUI/FormAuths.cs
i store the roles in the ticket here